# Rename jenkins on GitHub

Tags: jenkins

I've set up Jenkins with Blue Ocean and integrated it. It shows up properly on GitHub pull requests:

```
continuous-integration/jenkins/branch
continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge
```

Because we can have multiple instances of Jenkins which could run on the same repository I was wondering if it's possible to rename those "checks"

Something like this maybe:

```
continuous-integration/my-super-ci/branch
continuous-integration/my-super-ci/pr-merge
```

Do you know if this possible? I cannot find a way to do it. Maybe a plugin?

Thanks